# Bootstrap CodeIgniter without Routing to a Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

For command line scripts, tools, and (my current use case) accessing the CodeIgniter environment from another application - is there a way to 'bootstrap' CI without starting the routing process?

For example, with the Zend Framework I can setup the normal constants, create a `Zend_Application` instance, bootstrap the application, but as long as I don't call:

```
$application->run();
```

it won't start the route process, but I can still access the resources/models/etc of the application.

Is there a way to do that with CodeIgniter?

Comment: Have used little of CI and I have never seen that. But I have not dug that much!

Comment: From what I know, this is not possible. Even though the router is somehow a component of it's own, everything on that level it bake pretty much together in CI. Next to that, CI can only exist one time, you can not instantiate multiple controllers next to each other.

Comment: @hakre I figure I can force routing to a single controller (the ExpressionEngine code I've see does basically this), but you're saying once the controller finishes, CI may `die` on me, leaving me with nothing useful.

Comment: I tried to hack that out a week or two ago, but I run out of time and didn't manage it. The basic problem are the static function variables. Create a global array for contexts, so it allows you to overload that static shit (I guess that's still in there because of PHP 4 madness) with contexts. Then you should be able instantiate more than one controller (on controller per context), however no clue about how to remove the routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wordpress codeigniter plugin which has a bootstrap file. I think you can use it.

I played with it a little bit and if you are trying to load CodeIgniter's models/libraries etc, here is what you do:

1. Download the plugin from the link above and extract it.
2. There is a folder `ci_mods` which contains the bootstrap files. Copy this folder to your codeigniter directory (where system and application folders are).
3. ci_mods folder contains two files- `index.php` and `CodeIgniter.php`. Edit `index.php` and edit paths e.g. system path will become `$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../system';`
4. To prevent routing, comment line no. 342 in CodeIgniter.php

Now to use it in a file, just include `ci_mods/index.php` and you can do-

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->load->model('usermodel','',TRUE);

$q = $ci->usermodel->getUsers();
```

I haven't fully explored it yet. It might be more useful.

Here is my modified index.php

```
<?php

  // WARNING: This is not an original CI file

  // backuping query string
  $query_string = urlencode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

  // destroying the $_GET array (but reconstructed when CI leaves)
  $_GET = array();

  // let's use CI a bit to recover our $_GET array
  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '/cidip/recover_get_array/'.$query_string;  

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
    $system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller.php
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/CodeIgniter'.EXT;  

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

To the next unlucky person who has to deal with CI. For CI version 1.7 you can load up the instance by just doing this. Assuming you have defined the ROOT folder

```
<?php
define('APPPATH', ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS);
define('BASEPATH', ROOT . DS . 'system' . DS);
define('EXT', '.php');

require_once(BASEPATH . 'codeigniter/Common'.EXT);
require_once(BASEPATH . 'codeigniter/Base5'.EXT);
$controller =& load_class('Controller');
```

At this point you can call get_instance as you please or CI_Base::get_instance();

Found it to be useful for hacking unit tests against an old code base while we migrate it.